# Environment Variables NodeJS on Windows

Tags: node.js, heroku, environment-variables

I'm unable to get an environment variable to load properly on Windows OS for Node.

I tried dotenv originally, but I was having an issue where every URL was claiming it was undefined or NULL.

After giving it some thought I thought just 'requiring' the env should work, and it is. However, in my app.js I have `require('./env');` referencing an env.js file I saved. Then I noticed it wasn't trickling down to my modules/services, so I used 'if MIA' logic

```
if(!process.env.VAR_URL) {
    var env = require('../../../env.js')
}
```

Which worked, but I would have to do this for every single file. I thought including it in app.js would suffice. This feels extremely redundant, and I don't think is how I'm supposed to be doing it.

For Ref. my env.js (Which was .env) is -

```
process.env['MONGODB']="localhost:27017/test-collection"
process.env['MESSAGEURL']="http://localhost:3000/message/"
process.env['VAR_URL']="http://localhost:3000/"
```

The dotenv version of it I was trying was

```
MONGODB=localhost:27017/test-collection
MESSAGEURL=localhost:3000/message/
VAR_URL=localhost:3000/
```

Based on the docs I found on dotenv, you're not meant to double quote which is what I was thinking originally might be breaking my URLs.

I'm primarily a Rails user and used to just leveraging secrets.yaml - So I would prefer to do this the proper way, compared to whatever I've got going on.

(Node back-end, Ang2 front-end if that matters. I don't think it does since I'm getting the errors on Node/Express side)

UPDATE: I started using traditional env variables to store this data but I notice if I go through bundle.js I can see all of it unencrypted. Is this expected behavior, or how do you handle it securely?

Comment: Why can't you just set the environment variables?

Comment: @SLaks When I looked around on how to do that for NodeJS I kept finding references to embedding it into your `npm run script` and when I followed suit, the first one worked fine but as soon as I had a second && it started crashing. Is there another method to do that on Windows OS?

Comment: It doesn't matter.. You can still use windows's native env variable for nodejs. http://www.dowdandassociates.com/blog/content/howto-set-an-environment-variable-in-windows-command-line-and-registry/